# What is the best tool to query the text files(in compressed format) in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have imported the log files in compressed format from Database into HDFS. I am querying data using Hive CLI tool.

Could you please share other tools better than Hive for querying the data files?

Note: I am aware of Spark framework which I can use to query. But, I was wondering if there's any other option which is faster or/and offer SQL like syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about presto or impala?

Comment: "which is faster"... Well 1) This depends on your version of Hive 2) What Execution framework you use (please don't use MapReduce with Hive), and 3) What memory settings you allowed for

Answer (score 0):

Impala, Drill, PrestoDB and Amazon Redshift all accept SQL syntax and offer better performance.

For more info, see:

- https://impala.apache.org/
- https://drill.apache.org/
- https://prestodb.io/
- (AWS only) https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/